# Joining tables in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two tables

```
Customer                            Rate

    -------------                       -----------
    res_number                          product
    strategy                            name    
    fname                               type
    lname                               rate
    .....                               ......
```

And I created two beans

```
1.                                      2. 

    @Entity                                 @Entity
    @Table(name="customer")              @Table(name="rates")
    EmployeeDetails{                                CardDetails{
        @Col(name="res_number")             @col(name="product")
        String resNum;                          String product;
        .....                                       ....    

    }                                       }
```

Now the query I have is

```
hql = "from CardDetails cd, EmployeeDetails ed where ed.strategy = cd.product".
```

But it gives me reference problems saying `hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:`

I have tried adding

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "strategy")
    @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
    private EmployeeDetails empDetails;
```

in CardDetails  but it gives me error saying no OneToOne is possible ani... tried changing to ManyToOne and OneToMany but doesnot work. Can anyone please tell me how to map the beans for join using annotations? Note: The database is not designed correctly and there is no common field in both tables(like a foreign key). So any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Adding the beans:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rates")
public class CardDetails {
    @Id
    @Column(name="CARD_NAME")
    String cardName;
    @Column(name="CARD_TYPE")
    String cardType;
    @Column(name="FAQ_PAGE")
    String faqPage;
    @Column(name="GEN_INTRO_DISCL")
    String genIntroDiscl;
    @Column(name="GEN_REGULAR_RATE")
    String genRegularRate;
    @Column(name="BT_FEE")
    String btFee;
    @Column(name="BONUS")
    String bonus;
    @Column(name="ART_WORK")
    String artWork;
    @Column(name="DISCLOSURE_LINK")
    String disclosureLink;
    @Column(name="TERMS_LINK")
    String termsLink;
    @Column(name="PRODUCT")
    String product;

@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
@SecondaryTable(name="APPLICANT")
public class EmployeeDetails {
    @Id
    @Column(name="RESERVATION_NUMBER")
    String reservNumber;
    @Column(name="SSN")
    int ssnNumber;
    @Column(name="BANK_NUMBER")
    String bankNumber;
    @Column(name="BRANCH_NUMBER")
    String branchNumber;
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    String empId;
    @Column(name="STRATEGY")
    String strategy;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your HQL, you'd like to join the two tables using `stratety` in the Customer table and `product` in the Rate table.  This would imply that `strategy` is a foreign key.

If this is indeed a one-to-one relationship, then inside of CardDetails, try this:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product", referencedColumnName = "strategy")
private EmployeeDetails employeeDetails;
```

This assumes you don't already have `product` mapped as a property in CardDetails, if you do, you'll need to do it this way, otherwise Hibernate will complain about duplicate field mappings.

```
@Column(name = "product", columnDefinition = "char")
private String product;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product", referencedColumnName = "strategy", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private EmployeeDetails employeeDetails;
```

If it needs to be a one-to-many relationship, then do it this way:

```
@Column(name = "product", columnDefinition = "char")
private String product;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "product", referencedColumnName = "strategy", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<EmployeeDetails> employeeDetails;
```

Comment: Thanks much, Patrick. Do I have to do anything in EmployeeDetails class? Coz the error says `Column (reservation_number) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).`

The Original Query is 

`from CardDetails cd, EmployeeDetails ed where cd.product = ed.strategy and ed.resNumber=:reservNum";`

Comment: Your new query should simply be "from CardDetails as cd where cd.employeeDetails.resNumber = :resNumber"

Comment: It still gives me `Column (res_number) not found in any table in the query` :(

Comment: Your @Column references res_number, sounds like that's not the actual column name.

Comment: Thanks for immediate responses. I really appreciate it.. But I have checked the Column Name and it's the same. I have 

`@Entity
@Table(name="Customer")
@SecondaryTable(name="APPLICANT")
public class EmployeeDetails {
 @Id
 @Column(name="RES_NUMBER")
 String resNumber;`

Does that secondary table matter? Is it why its failing?

Comment: I've never used @SecondaryTable before.  See what happens if you remove it.

Comment: It gives me other errors because `EmployeeDetails` class has other properties which are from other table(Applicant).. How can I specify them then?

Comment: Sounds like your mappings need fixing.  If Applicant is related to EmployeeDetails, then try doing it with a OneToOne or ManyToOne, whatever the relation may be.  In practice, I wouldn't add properties to one entity that are actually part of a different table entirely.  Maybe post your entities completely so I can see.

Comment: Sure. The thing is I have a form which has fields associated with multiple tables. I have created the bean corresponding to that form including the columns from multiple tables(I don't know if that's the way to do it). That's why there is problems with mappings. I am posting the actual beans as an Edit to the original question.

Thanks for the answers. Truly appreciated!

Comment: The interesting thing is even if I do `"from CardDetails as cd where cd.employeeDetails.strategy = 'P123'"` , it gives me the same error `"Column (res_number) not found in any table in the query "`

Comment: That's because it's not complaining about your query.  It's complaining about your column mappings.  For the sake of testing, what happens if you remove the SecondaryTable annotation and remove all fields associated to Applicant from EmployeeDetails?

Comment: It is still giving me the same error. I have removed the `@column`  and `@SecondaryTable` Annotations

Comment: Ok, now remove your reservation number @Column and take it out of your query.  It shouldn't throw the same error.

Comment: Wait.. Now its giving me a different error. I still have reservation_number but it's failing at `  List<CardDetails> cardDetailsList = query.list();`

Comment: Probably because it was your @Id field.  I still think the column name is what's incorrect.

Comment: It gives `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.theConnection.pnc.model.EmployeeDetails cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable`

Comment: In that case, it pretty well confirms my suspicions about the column name.

Comment: Here's my code.
`if (empDetails.getReservNumber().startsWith("P")) {
      hql =  "FROM CardDetails as cd WHERE cd.employeeDetails.reservNumber = :resNumber";
     }else{
      hql = "from CardDetails cd, EmployeeDetails ed "
        + "where cd.product = ed.upc12[1,4] and ed.reservation_number=:resNum";
     }
     Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
     query.setString("resNumber", empDetails.getReservNumber());
     List<CardDetails> cardDetailsList = query.list();
  return  cardDetailsList.get(0);`

Comment: It is failing at query.list() part.

Comment: Which query actually runs?  You're listing 2 possible queries.  The second one should be updated as well with the cd.employeeDetails.resNumber.  Also make sure you're spelling everything correctly.  There's a lot of inconsistencies in all your code snippets about the spelling of the resNumber field and column name.

Comment: Don't care about the first second one now.. I have changed the bean names and column names at first just for security... but I am using the same names.

Comment: Can you tell me how to assign the result of the hql query to the CardDetails object?

Comment: `hql= "FROM CardDetails as cd WHERE cd.employeeDetails.reservNumber = :resNumber";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
 query.setString("resNumber", empDetails.getReservNumber());
List<CardDetails> cardDetailsList = query.list();
return  cardDetailsList.get(0);`

Is it correct?

Comment: It gives me error at

`query.list()`
`com.theConnection.pnc.model.EmployeeDetails cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable`

Comment: query is from CardDetails.. why does it give EmployeeDetails cannot be cast to?? I dont understand

Comment: Does EmployeeDetails implement Serializable?  If not, try adding that.

Comment: I will add but can I know why?

Comment: Because the exception says it's trying to cast EmployeeDetails to Serializable.

Comment: Ohk.. But now it is giving me other error saying cannot find the column bank number.. This is so exhausting:(

Comment: Can you tell me how we would go about this scenario?

`I have one form with fields from multiple tables...`
I thought I would create a bean for all those fields... Isn't that true? And that's why in that bean, I have included multiple fields....

Comment: You can do that yes, so long as you can convert it on the server to the desired entity.  I'm not sure what the issue is at this point.  Mapping isn't this complicated in my experience.

Comment: So Can you please tell me how to map a bean which has properties from multiple tables? Right now, I am using the @SecondaryTable annotation and that is causing the problem.

Comment: I've never done that before to be honest.  See if these help http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/secondarytables_hibernate_annotation or http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/SecondaryTableWithPrimaryKey.htm

Comment: I don't have a key(primary) to map the two tables:( Let's say I create different beans for each table.. Is there a way to use them combine in a form?